# Where to place user created systemd unit files

Tags: systemd

Where should I put systemd file for e.g. Nginx `nginx.service` or something like that on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the [nginx packages in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/nginx)? `nginx-common` seems to have a systemd unit file, too

Comment: No there is nothing wrong. I just tried to compile nginx from source and want to be able to control it via sysctl.

Comment: @user3448600> even when compiling from source, you should normally build a package and `dpkg --install` that package. Should you do that, the correct place for service descriptions is `/lib/systemd/system`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The recommended place is `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service`

Then issue the command :

```
systemctl enable nginx
```

And finally

```
systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: Daemon reload is only need when you change a file that is already in use. By enabling the service nginx, there is no need for daemon-reload.

Comment: It would just say service not found until you daemon reload

Comment: M. Kudriavtsev is wrong.  `systemctl enable` enacts a reload, as its manual page does say.  An explicit reload is not necessary.

Answer (score 22):

Usually, in Ubuntu, the package provided unit files go in `/lib/systemd/system/` directory e.g. `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` whereas the user provided or any modification to the package provided unit file(s) go in `/etc/systemd/system/` directory.

Now, to override, you can:

- Name the unit file as the package provided one e.g. to override `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`, you can create the file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` and put the directives in there
- Or you can create a drop-in snippet ending in `.conf` in a directory that is named after the original unit file with `.d` appended to the directory name e.g. you can create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf` and put statements in there

---

Now, you can leverage the `systemctl edit` command to do all the manual stuffs for you i.e. it will create the necessary override file for you (at first it will create a temporary file (with intermediate directory(ies) for drop-in snippets), and upon saving it will commit and `rename()` the temp file to desired final file), and you just need to edit the file to put in your overrides.

For example, to create an override snippet for `ngnx.service` (`/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`) mentioned above:

```
systemctl edit nginx.service
```

By default, it will use the file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf`. If `--full` is used then the full replacement file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` will be used (*the original content from `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` will be copied to this file*).

You can also use `--runtime` to create the snippet in `/run/systemd/system/` (at first drop-in snippet, then whole so `--runtime` and `--full` are not mutually-exclusive) that will be temporary of course.

You can obviously choose the editor to use, the order of precedence is:

```
$SYSTEMD_EDITOR > $EDITOR > $VISUAL > editor > nano > vim > vi
```

Comment: Is there a reason you reverted my revision? The edit fixes inaccurate information in your answer. I even provided you with documentation supporting the changes.

Comment: @Patrick sorry about that. Ubuntu doesn't comply with the locations, well, not to the extent that would be helpful to end users...also, `/lib/` (and `/usr/lib/`) are not symlinks in Ubuntu...